# What is the correct way to know where a file is located on HDFS cluster?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-partitioning

I need to develop my own job executor (it is not homework) leveraging on datanode [locality](http://hadoopinrealworld.com/data-locality-in-hadoop/).

I have a cluster (2 datanodes) of Hadoop 2.7.1 .

[image]
(see http://jugsi.blogspot.it/2017/08/configuring-hadoop-271-on-windows-w-ssh.html)

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    //conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
    System.out.println(FileSystem.get(conf));

    check(conf, "hdfs://localhost:19000/LICENSE.txt");
    check(conf, "hdfs://localhost:19000/test.txt");
    check(conf, "hdfs://localhost:19000/DOESNEXIST.txt");

}

public static void check(Configuration conf, String path) throws Exception {
    try {
        URI uri = URI.create (path);
        System.out.println(path);
        FileSystem file = FileSystem.get(uri, conf);
        Path p = new Path(uri);
        System.out.println(file);

        BlockLocation[] locations = file.getFileBlockLocations(p, 0, 128*1024*1024*1024);
        for (BlockLocation blockLocation : locations) {
            System.out.println(blockLocation);
        }

        FSDataInputStream in = file.open(p);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { //truncate file
            int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (rsz < 0)
                break;
           System.out.print(new String(buffer, 0, rsz));
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

replication is 1 and

on master:

```
hadoop fs -put LICENSE.txt /
```

on slave:

```
hadoop fs -put test.txt /
```

and it works,

> hdfs://localhost:19000/LICENSE.txt
>   DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1132409281_1,
>   ugi=212442540 (auth:SIMPLE)]] 0,15429,MASTER

and

> hdfs://localhost:19000/test.txt
>   DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1132409281_1,
>   ugi=212442540 (auth:SIMPLE)]] 0,4,SLAVE

but it seems to me like a workaround. **How Spark or Yarn ask for file location in order to put the job close (into) to the datanode?**